# Can I use a Schengen visa issued the French Embassy to enter the Netherlands

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, france

i'm working for a French company. I was supposed to travel to France for some time but the travel has been delayed and I haven't used the visa issued for that trip. I am  going to visit the Netherlands for a 2-day interview. Can I use my current visa to do that?  If not, am I able to get another visa as the current one is valid for another for 6 months?

Comment: what kind of visa do you have? Is it a Schengen visitors visa?

Comment: Is it a C or D visa?

Comment: the visa type is c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use that visa.  You won't get in trouble unless you are suspected of having obtained the visa by fraud, so you may get a question about why you haven't used it before.  If you do, it may be helpful to show evidence to support your assertion that "the travel has been delayed," for example, e-mail messages about planning the trip and about cancelling or postponing it.

Of course, you also need to be able to justify your trip to the Netherlands, so you should be prepared to show evidence of your interview.

You don't need to offer the evidence when you approach the passport counter.  Just show your visa and answer any questions you're asked.  Offer the evidence if the officer seems skeptical, or, of course, if you are asked for it explicitly.